# Poisson Summation Formula and Swapping Sum and Integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, summation, fourier-series

According to, say, Wikipedia, the Poisson Summation Formula states that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty S(k),$$ where $$S(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x) e^{-2\pi i k x}dx.$$  Now from, say, the DLMF, we also have the formal series representation of the Dirac delta function, $$\delta(x-a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{ik(x-a)}.$$  Combining the above, we should then have that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty S(k) \\ = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x) e^{-2\pi i k x}dx \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x)\left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi i k x} \right) dx \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x)\delta(x) dx \\ = s(0).$$

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s(n) = s(0)$ cannot be correct in general.  So what went wrong?

Presumably the swapping of the sum and the integral is the source of the issue.  If so, my question, then, is: when is the swapping of the sum and the integral in this case valid?

Further, clearly $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s(n) = s(0)$ when $s(x)$ is odd, $s(-n)=-s(n)$; are there more general conditions for $s(x)$ such that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty s(n) = s(0)$?

Thank you very much for your insight!

Comment: Can you provide the link to the relevant DLMF page? Note that we should have $$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta\left(x-2\pi k - a\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ik(x-a)} $$ on $\mathbb{R}$, due to the periodicity of the right-hand side. (Just for reference, this is called the Dirac comb.)

Comment: I believe it's pretty well known from many sources, but the relevant DLMF link is https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17#E21.  That said, maybe you've put your finger on the issue :-)

Comment: Although it is not clearly described, all the formulas in that subsection seem to be developed on a suitable space of functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$ (or more precisely, $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$), in which case the representation is valid as generalized functions on that domain (rather than on $\mathbb{R}$). Given this, it is not surprising that the formula does not properly apply to functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh gosh!  Yes, I see clearly now the integration region restriction $(-\pi,\pi)$ in the first equation of that subsection.  Well spotted, and thank you!